# jQuery, check if .detach variable is empty or has detached data stored?

Tags: jquery

I have a this function below with is fired when a onClick takes place + uses a ref.

I have managed to get the .detach to successfully work.

But when my function runs a second time, I would like to check if the `detachedMini` actually contains anything so I can re-attach it, before then detaching the next lot.

```
bikeFilter = function (y) {

    var detachedMini,
        detachedMain;

    bikeDetach = function () {

        detachedMini = $('#bike-mini-slider .bike[data-group!=' + y + ']');
        detachedMain = $('#bike-main-slider .bike[data-group!=' + y + ']');

        detachedMini.detach();
        detachedMain.detach();

    };

    if ( !detachedMini == 0 ) {

        $('#bike-mini-slider .bike').append(detachedMini);
        $('#bike-main slider .bike').append(detachedMain);

    }                       

    bikeDetach();

};
```

I've tried this...

```
if ( !detachedMini == 0 ) {
```

But I don't think its working correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property of jQuery objects:

```
if (detachedMini.length) {
    $('#bike-mini-slider .bike').append(detachedMini);
    $('#bike-main slider .bike').append(detachedMain);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm thanks - I getting undefined error length, so maybe I've got my scope mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ( detachedMini.length != 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
bikeFilter = function (y) {

    var detachedMini = null,
        detachedMain = null;

    bikeDetach = function () {

        detachedMini = $('#bike-mini-slider .bike[data-group!=' + y + ']').detach();
        detachedMain = $('#bike-main-slider .bike[data-group!=' + y + ']').detach();

    };

    if ( typeof(detachedMini) != "null" ) {

        $('#bike-mini-slider .bike').append(detachedMini);
        $('#bike-main slider .bike').append(detachedMain);

    }                       

    bikeDetach();

};
```